# "More" span making trouble

Tags: custom-post-types, read-more

I've created my own custom post type using this tutorial: http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/

Everything works fine, but I'm having major problem with "Read more" feature.

As we all know `<!--more-->` adds `<span id="more-[number]" />` at the start of hidden more paragraph. In my case this span breaks whole markup.

See for yourself:

```
    <p>This is normal paragraph and should be visible everywhere.</p>

    <!-- everything below is available only after clicking "Read more..." button -->

    <p><span id="more-[postnumber] />This is read "more" paragraph that will be displayed only on a "single" page.</p>
    <p>And another "more" paragraph.</p>
```

In my case it creates this strange code:

```
  <p>This is normal paragraph and should be visible everywhere.<br/>
  <span id="more-[postnumber] /></br>This is read "more" paragraph that will be displayed only on a "single" page.</p>
  <p>And another "more" paragraph.</p>
```

So the more feature in my case doesn't even work and doesn't even display "Read more" button.

Any ideas?

[EDITED]

Ok, so I've added whitespace after and before my `<!--more-->` tag, so the post looks like this in admin panel now:

```
This is normal paragraph and should be visible everywhere.

<!--more-->

This is read "more" paragraph that will be displayed only on a "single" page.

And another "more" paragraph.
```

And it outputs the whole text because more span is getting an additional paragraph (why? :O):

```
<p>This is normal paragraph and should be visible everywhere.</p>
<p><span id="more-[postnumber] /></p> <!-- I believe it shouldn't be in the additional <p> tag and that's the point -->
<p>This is read "more" paragraph that will be displayed only on a "single" page.</p>
<p>And another "more" paragraph.</p>
```

And about "more button" - I'm using the_content unfortunately...

And nothing helps, when I type 'TRUE' as the second parameter - the_content('Read more...', TRUE); - it hides everything BEFORE more tag (so it shows two last paragraphs and hides the first one).

What's that? :O

Comment: For the record _more_ span **is** supposed to be in separate `p` tag. That is intended and normal. When you say _hides_ do you meant stuff disappears from page source? Could this be CSS issue?

Comment: Nope, it's not. I've checked plenty of custom themes with custom post names and I noticed that EVERY SINGLE one is using the_excerpt() function instead of the_content. So I've decided to switch and add an a href with permalink below. And it works. I believe there's something wrong with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  quicktag will not operate and is ignored in Templates, such as single.php, where just one post is displayed. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 3):

So, two separate issues - links not displaying and faulty markup?

For links not displaying - check if your template uses `the_content()` function, *more* functionality doesn't display links after `the_excerpt()`.

For markup I find that you need blank lines around *more* for everything to work properly.

So this can cause markup issues:

```
Some text here.
<!--more-->
And more here.
```

But this works fine:

```
Some text here.

<!--more-->

And more here.
```

Comment: Nothing works. Thanks for trying. I'm going to update the first post and explain what I've already tried...