# More tag - how do I remove preceding <br>?

Tags: customization, read-more

Can anyone advise on how I can remove the preceding `<br>` tag when a post's "read more..." tag is generated?

Any advice appreciated!

This is the code that's generated -

```
<p>blah blah blah blah<br>
 <a class="more-link" href="blahblahblahblah"> …Read more</a></p>
```

It's that annoying little 
 I want rid of, so the "read more" is on the same line...!

Comment: Check out [this answer of mine on "more span making trouble" question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/more-span-making-trouble/5045#5045), I am not sure if you are referring to same issue as that question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the code being generated for me isn't in a span, it just has <br> then an anchor tag for the read more. Should there be a span around it?

Comment: @Cordial: Please add the fragment of your theme that inserts the more link to your question. Please name the theme you are using.

Comment: @Cordial does adding blank lines around _more_ tag, as described in that answer, in editor help?

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us your generated source code with more tag and code which you use for this?

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
function clear_br($excerpt){
return str_replace("<br>","", $excerpt);
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'clear_br');
```

Paste this code in your **functions.php**

Answer (score 0):

You'll wanna make a filter in your functions.php file. Scroll about halfway down on this codex page and they'll show two separate methods.

[the_excerpt on WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

Also, make sure your existing functions file doesn't already have something like this, which could be adding the line break in the first place.